# How to get Octopack to use custom .nuspec file?

Tags: octopus-deploy, nuspec

The documentation seems to be really incomplete.  All it says is that you *can* use your own .nuspec file, but it makes no mention of where you're supposed to put it, or how to get octopack to use it.

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack

I've tried naming the .nuspec file the same thing that my solution is named and having it in the same directory.  That didn't work.

I've tried modifying the .nuspec file that Octopack generates, but those changes just get overwritten every time I run it.

Everything else I try is just a shot in the dark.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

blerg.

I'm a dummy.

The .nuspec file needs to be in the same directory as the .csproj file.  This actually makes sense because it allows you to have a different nuspec file for each project in your solution.

Hopefully this post helps someone else.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use a custom nuspec file (something different than `your.project.name.nuspec`, there is a msbuild property [`OctoPackNuSpecFileName`](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/1425-teamcity-octopus-selecting-the-nuspec-file-per-environment), through wich you can specify your nuspec file, like this:

```
msbuild yoursolution.sln /p:RunOctoPack=true p:OctoPackNuSpecFileName=Dev.nuspec
```

Comment: You can also use custom or conditional .nuspec files by modifying your .csproj file. See answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to use a custom or conditional .nuspec file with OctoPack is by adding a PropertyGroup to your .csproj file, like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RunOctoPack>true</RunOctoPack>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <OctoPackNuSpecFileName Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">MyApp.nuspec</OctoPackNuSpecFileName>
  <OctoPackNuSpecFileName Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">MyApp.Debug.nuspec</OctoPackNuSpecFileName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Put the files MyApp.nuspec and MyApp.Debug.nuspec in the same directory as your .csproj file and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Note, you don't *have* to have NuSpec as the OctoPack will generate one on the fly (based off the project file) if it's not there - that's what you were experiencing.

Granted, if you want to customize the NuGet package, the NuSpec is required. Check out the OctoPack source here:  https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack and you can see for yourself how the OctoPack works with the NuSpec.

Comment: yeah, my solution file has a space in its name, so the package that octopack was trying to create had an invalid name.  That's why I needed to explicitly specify the package name in the nuspec.